# Adding jQuery capabilities to a browser

Tags: jquery, browser, autoload

Sometimes I need to remove some elements on a web page or execute some jQuery functions on that page using Javascript command like or just address bar with `javascript:doSomething;void;`.

However later on I found that I can add jQuery to a page with **jQuerify** bookmarklet: http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/12/jquerify-bookmarklet

Is there a chance that I can have jQuery environment loaded in browser by default on any page automatically? (I mean without using that bookmarklet and loading the same jquery-latest.js everytime.)

Thanks.

Comment: If the jQuery filename is the same, it's already on your system and being reloaded from cache.

Comment: does not matter whether it is cached. it is going to be reloaded when cache miss occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a Greasemonkey script that looks something like this:

```
var $;

// Add jQuery
    (function(){
        if (typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') {
            var GM_Head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.documentElement,
                GM_JQ = document.createElement('script');

            GM_JQ.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js';
            GM_JQ.type = 'text/javascript';
            GM_JQ.async = true;

            GM_Head.insertBefore(GM_JQ, GM_Head.firstChild);
        }
        GM_wait();
    })();

// Check if jQuery's loaded
    function GM_wait() {
        if (typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') {
            window.setTimeout(GM_wait, 100);
        } else {
            $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery.noConflict(true);
            letsJQuery();
        }
    }

// All your GM code must be inside this function
    function letsJQuery() {
       /* Execute stuff here */
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to use Firefox. I'm looking for some other elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can install something greasemonkey and run your custom scripts on any page automatically.

Comment: I don't want to use Firefox. I'm looking for some other elegant solution.

Comment: I think there is equivalent of greasemonkey for IE (http://www.gm4ie.com/) and Chrome (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) too.

Comment: And if you don't want to use greasemonkey at all, you may need to roll out your own Chrome extension or IE/FF addon.